Tensorflow map_fn do not pass variable to lambda function
I am trying to code BERT model, with 15% token masked. To create mask token, I first create a tensor with actual length (85% first token is 1, the other is 0) with sequence_mask. Then I shuffle it, then pad it to max length, by padding zero. But some problem when I use map_fn, it do not create the tensor I want, it should be (64,1,MAX_LENGTH).
def generate_sequence(actual_length, MAX_LENGTH):
    one_tensor = tf.cast(tf.cast(actual_length, tf.float32) * 0.85, tf.int64)

    masked_sequence = tf.random.shuffle(tf.sequence_mask(one_tensor, maxlen=actual_length, dtype=tf.int64))

    padded_sequence = tf.pad(masked_sequence, paddings=[[0, MAX_LENGTH - actual_length]], mode='CONSTANT',
                             constant_values=0.0)
    
    return padded_sequence


def create_random_mask(input_tokens, actual_lengths):
    # input_tokens has shape (64,16,10)
    # actual_lengths has shape (64,)
    batch_size, sentence_len = input_tokens.shape[0], input_tokens.shape[1]
    
    mask = tf.map_fn(lambda length: generate_sequence(length, sentence_len), actual_lengths, dtype=tf.int64) # return (64,None)
    mask = tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=1) # return (64,1,None)
    
    return mask

I guess that because when I use my following create_padding_mask function, it works:
def create_padding_mask(input_tokens, actual_lengths):
    batch_size, sentence_len = tf.shape(input_tokens)[0], tf.shape(input_tokens)[1]

    mask = tf.sequence_mask(actual_lengths, maxlen=sentence_len, dtype=tf.float32)

    mask = tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=1)

    return mask #return (64,1,MAX_LENGTH)

Please help me to find out where the problem is. Thanks so much.

Hi @Thanh , You need to change you code because tf.map_fn works element-wise, it is not handling the padding ,reshaping ,shuffling the mask. For that you need to check some points ,Mask should be padded properly for each sentence, second point is tf.random.shuffle already produces a tensor with the shape, Try it if you still facing some isssue let me,Thank.
